# django mod_wsgi, nginx MySQL or Postgres

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql, nginx

I am looking to find out from the community which you think is best?

Django running with the following.

Django, mod_wsgi and MySQL
Django, mod_wsgi and Postgres
Django, nginx and MySQL
OR
Django, nginx and Postgres

?

Comment: There is no single answer. The correct choice depends entirely on your project requirements, where it’s hosted, office politics…

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/585549/164552

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>I use nginx because it's faster and I like how the configuration is set up. I have never run into any trouble using it so I can't see why one should rather use Apache + mod_wsgi.</strike>

Also, using fastcgi, you can restart your django site without restarting the whole nginx server, which I like.

And Postgres because:

> If you're not tied to any legacy system and have the freedom to choose a database back-end, we recommend PostgreSQL, which achives a fine balance between cost, features, speed and stability. (The Definitive Guide to Django, p. 15)

Copied from: [MySQL vs PostgreSQL? Which should I choose for my Django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585549/mysql-vs-postgresql-which-should-i-choose-for-my-django-project)

**EDIT:**

I now think that **uwsgi** running behind a load balancer (**varnish**) is the best solution. **nginx** can then be used to serve static content.

See "**Varnish and nginx, the best way (0.9.8.4)**" @ http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Example

You can use *Emperor* ( http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Emperor) for managing apps in **uwsgi**. This will allow you to restart individual apps by simply *touching* their config files.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this benchmark](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers) Django+ uWSGI wins.

Comment: Flawed benchmark. One would never run Apache with 1000 threads per child. That they configured Apache in a sub optimal way, it is not surprising then that Apache shows an excessive amount of memory being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nginx as a proxy and have apache run on localhost.

To start a single django project, you'd touch the wsgi file for that project and it will only reload that instance of django. You don't need to restart/reload apache