# Creating a development environment for Django

Tags: django, apache, development-environment

We are starting a web project with Django (and are pretty new to this), and I was wondering what would been the best way to setup a productive development environment.

Here is some info:

- We are 2 developers working on the project
- We have a development/production server hosted on Webfactional (using an apache server)
- The DB (MySQL) is hosted on this server
- We are both using Eclipse with Pydev
- The project is hosted on a Github repository

So far, we didn't setup any local development server, we are syncing modifications to the server through Github. But it is not really convenient...

We were thinking of setting up apache servers locally, that uses the remote database, and only sync once in a while.

Do you think it would be better?

Do you have other ideas/additional tips?

Thanks!

Comment: You could set up a specific DB on the server (mirroring the production one) for development and connect to it over the network (through an SSH tunnel for example). This avoids the mess of migrations and keeping in sync

Comment: As a side note, since you're just getting started and probably don't have any ties to a DB yet, I'd recommend using PostgreSQL as your DB. I'm also developing using Django on webfaction and after switching from MySQL to PostgreSQL my life has been significantly easier. The creators of Django highly recommend using Postgres too.

Comment: @Spike Thanks for the advice, I was just going with MySQL in the first place because, coming from the PHP world, I know it better. But I don't have any argument for this. Do you know why Postgre is recommended over MySQL? Is it highly scalable as well? Thanks!

Comment: @pastylegs That is a good idea, I should do this. Thanks

Comment: here's a link with some answers that explain it better than I can: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585549/mysql-vs-postgresql-which-should-i-choose-for-my-django-project. On top of what they said there, I found that using django-south was MUCH easier while using Postgres than with MySQL. I know there are other database migration tools out there that also work better with Postgres as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't try and share servers and databases while you're developing. You'll only get confused.

Each developer should have a local copy of MySQL on their own machine, and run the development server as mipadi recommends. Manage db schema changes via South, and keep data in fixtures or use South's data migrations. Each developer should commit to their local version of the git repository, but only push changes to Github when the particular task is complete and working (or, better, use a remote branch so that changes are synched, but only merge back to master when complete).

A good idea is to have a continuous integration server like Hudson/Jenkins that, after each commit to master, runs the tests and - if they pass - builds an up-to-date version of the site, which you can use for functional/user testing.

**Edit to add** There's no relationship between the development server and any particular database backend. As I recommend above, it is quite simple to install MySQL or PostgreSQL on your local machine, and use the development server against that. I have been working this way for several years, after initially encountering some of the issues you were worried about when switching between sqlite3 and the production MySQL db.

Comment: Thank's, it is exactly the kind of advice/recommendation I needed. Same question though: Isn't it painful to move from the local server to the remote one if they are not using the same webserver/DB? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Django has its own [development server](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port) that you can use for local testing.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that. I didn't think it was a good idea in the first place because it is not using the same DB (SQLite, from what I read) and the same server, so I was worried it would make migrating from local development to the remote dev server painful. What do you think?

Comment: @nbarraille: Probably don't want to run testing against a production database anyway. Also, you can use whatever (supported) server backend you want in development mode, including MySQL.