# Group_by Django list

Tags: sql, django, group-by

I have a django model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    """" Modelo criado com referencia ao modelo remoto """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    born = models.DateField()
```

I want to group all the people by birthday (group by born date).
I'm trying to get a dictionary of dictionaries, like this:

```
{ 
    02-17:[
            {
               name:'Daniel',
               age:22
            },
            {
               name:'Pedro',
               age:23
            },
          ],
    05-24:[
            {
               name:'Juan',
               age:44
            }
          ]
}
```

One option is:

```
query = Person.objects.all().query
query.group_by = ['born']

for item in QuerySet(query=query, model=Person):
    print item
```

but it returns a list with all objects ordered by date... no grouped.

Can I do this by django ORM or with sql raw? 
I will have to do it by myself?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on Postgres, extract may work also on MySQL but I'm not sure if it will work on any other database.

```
from django.db.models import Count

Person.objects.extra(select={'day': 'extract( day from born )', 'month': 'extract ( month from born )'}).values('day', 'month').annotate(num=Count('born'))
```

Comment: Hi, I run that and get... **django.db.utils.DatabaseError: near "from": syntax error**

Comment: Hi Daniel, wich database engine are you using?

Comment: Im using sqlite3 but I can change it to other one if I need to, what should I use?

Comment: Difficult question... :) I personally prefer PostgreSQL but MySQL can do the job fine. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585549/mysql-vs-postgresql-which-should-i-choose-for-my-django-project