# django different databases benchmark?

Tags: database, django, django-models, django-orm

I am of course aware that django offers fantastic ORM, and the choosen db is in fact transparent from the point of view of programmer, but at the end of the day it is converted to some SQL executed in certain database.

Are there some benchmarks of how fast same django queries will be executed in different databases?

Comment: This [MySQL vs PostgreSQL which should I choose for my Django project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585549/mysql-vs-postgresql-which-should-i-choose-for-my-django-project) question and answers there might be helpful for you

Comment: @AamirAdnan I've red it, but there is not much about speed, rather additional things you can gain from using one or another. Anyway looking for some concrete numbers of common operations like filters will be cool, and also comparision with some commercial Oracle db.

Comment: Just in case you don't find these benchmarks, I think it's not very time-consuming to do it yourself (just the time to set 3 dbs and create some weird db request ^^). The main advantage I see is that you can test exactly what you want to know, and that will be more relevant than generic results.

Comment: You're probably off track. It's extremely unlikely that a difference between my MySQL or Postgresql or Oracle or whatever will be critical. Put effort into your database layout, tweak the slow queries, cache what you can and buy more hardware.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested Database performance using Django ORM

Here is my finding about insert of 1000 rows(smaller is better)
[image: PostgreSQL vs MySQL vs MariaDB vs SQLite]

full result in

https://github.com/sarathak/django-db-benchmark